# Flink SQL: Do not materialize NULL fields when inserting into MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-flink, flink-sql, sql-null

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    _id STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,
    a INT
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'mongodb',
      'uri' = 'mongodb://user:password@database:27017',
      'database' = 'database',
      'collection' = 'test'
      );

INSERT INTO test
VALUES ('id',
           (SELECT bar
        FROM (SELECT 1 AS foo)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 2 AS bar)
        ON foo = bar));
```

Desired result in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : "id"}
```

Actual:

```
{ "_id" : "id", "a" : null }
```

Is it possible to not materialize the field with NULL value using just Flink SQL or will I have to use the datastream API?

I could not find any option to change this behaviour in the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/table/mongodb/).

Comment: I ended forking the connector to change the behaviour to omit null fields. https://github.com/jj314/flink-connector-mongodb/commit/29e459ed82a96dc8ea76a3698b6600174204c19f